# Singing and the Song tradition

Tags: shadow-of-the-demon-lord

How does singing work? I assume only one song can be sung at the same time? Can you keep singing for free or does it take an action? I don't see any singing mechanics mentioned anywhere.

For example, the following spell

> SONG OF INSPIRATION SONG UTILITY 1 Duration 1 minute When you cast the
> spell, and on each of your turns for the duration, choose one creature
> within short range of you that can hear you. The target makes its next
> attack roll or challenge roll with 2 boons. The effect ends
> immediately if you stop singing or cast another spell.

suggests that you can keep singing for free (since at level 1 it should be better than Uplifting Melody which requires concentration and so does require an action each turn).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a book-safe response (*I can't quote the chapter, page and verse from the manual*) but in the absence of same our group created some workable rules that seem to maintain game balance and playability.

The assumption that only one Song can be sung at a time is spot-on.  Singing takes an action, especially if it results in a magical effect (*because it requires primo concentration to control the magic*).  Recordings don't create the same effect because they cannot actively release and/or control the magic.  If a creature (*see how non-specific I'm getting here?*) has more than one voice/speaking apparatus then THEY might be able to sing two songs at once - or set up a harmony to improve the efficacy of the song/spell that they are currently singing.  But that's an extremely rare exception, and you shouldn't encounter it often.  But if they follow general human anatomy they will only be able to sing one song at a time, and if their song releases magical effects (*I never called it a spell directly*) singing it will require concentration to create and maintain the effect.

That ruling not only makes sense but it keeps the Munchkins from trying to confuse things by stacking song/spell effects.  Just some common sense applied to gaming - and it seems to work for us.  So far, anyway.

Comment: The "singing takes an action" ruling seems very wrong to me. What about spells that require singing and concentration. You can't do them at all? If you are saying that concentration includes singing it still doesn't make sense. Compare the level 1 spell Song of inspiration with the level 0 cantrip Uplifiting melody. The only difference is that one requires concentration (and singing) and the other only singing. Clearly the former is supposed to be freeing up actions hence justifying the increased level.

Comment: We all thought that was just poor rule-writing.  Of course, we were mostly musicians in the real world, so maybe we were allowing the basics of reality to interfere where rules-lawyers seek to obtain.  Our final test: "Try it some time."  YMMV.